# Forming the graph $G$ from elements of the cut and cycle space, using a weird hint

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm working through a set of lecture notes on my own, and since there is no class, there are no immediate faculty members available to ask questions to. I've managed to finish most exercises quite satisfactory, but this one still baffles me, in large part because the hint seems very unintuitive to me.

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a graph, and $W(G)$ be the edge space, which is a linear space with the field $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \{0, 1\}$ and addition and multiplication modulo 2.

We write the edges of the graph as a vector $(x_1, \dots, x_m)$, with $x_i = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} 1 & \text{if $e_i$ is in the subset} \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \end{array} \right.$

Also, we define $W_{S}(G)$ as the cut space of $G$, and $W_{C}(G)$ as the cycle space. Finally, for a random spanning tree $T$ we define $C_T(G)$ as the corresponding cycle matrix and $S_T(G)$ as the corresponding cut matrix.

The exercise is as follows:

Prove that for every graph $G$ there are vectors $c \in W_C(G)$ and $s \in W_S(G)$ are such that $c + s = (1,1, \dots, 1)$.

The hint is:

Show that the matrices $(C_T(G), S_T(G), e)^T$ and $(C_T(G), S_T(G))^T$, where $e = (1,1,\dots,1)$, have equal dimensions of the nullspace, and thus have the same rank.

I've not managed to work out this exercise on my own, and the hint perplexes me. A search on the internet has shown no results either.. My linear algebra is a little rusty, since it's been some years, so to me this seems like a very strange thing..

I hope someone can explain the hint to me and help with the proof, or point me in the direction of a proof somewhere on the internet. Thank you!

Comment: You mean addition and multiplication modulo$~2$. Integer arithmetic modulo$~1$ is not very interesting.

Comment: You're absolutely right, that's a typo!

Comment: What is the cut space?

Comment: modulo 1 is always 0

Comment: Hint: The direct sum of the cycle space and the cut space is the whole space.